# GRPC performance vs WCF performance

Tags: c#, wcf, grpc

We have a legacy app that runs on top of WCF, so we are trying to move off of it, and find another technology. One of the problems is that we need performance from the wire, so part of evaluating GRPC is evaluating how quickly it works, but also how many simultaneous clients we can run.

So, to that end, we're simulating many calls with relatively low amount of data being passed through, but high number of calls. In that respect, WCF has turned out to be significantly better than GRPC, which is very unexpected. Is there possibly something wrong with the way the test were conceived and implemented?

The server code:

```
public override Task<TestReply> Test(TestRequest request, ServerCallContext context)
{
  var ret = new char[request.Size];
  var a = (int)'a';
  for (var i = 0; i < request.Size; i++)
  {
    ret[i] = (char)(a + (i % 26));
  }
  return Task.FromResult(new TestReply { Message = new string(ret) });
}
```

The client code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   AppContext.SetSwitch("System.Net.Http.SocketsHttpHandler.Http2UnencryptedSupport", true);
   using var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("http://remote_server:8001", new GrpcChannelOptions { Credentials = ChannelCredentials.Insecure });

   var client = new Greeter.GreeterClient(channel);
   string TestMethod(int i)
   {
      var request = new TestRequest {Size = i};
      return client.Test(request).Message;
   }

   var start = DateTime.Now;
   for (var i = 0; i < 15625; i++)
   {
      var val = TestMethod(10);
   }
   var end = DateTime.Now;
}
```

If we run one a single instance of the client, it takes just under 7 seconds. If we run 64 instances simultaneously, each takes an average of 23 seconds. Part of the problem is that running 64 instances is also CPU intensive, on both client and server. With 64 clients, the client will see 85-95% CPU utilization, and the server will see 70-80%.

By comparison, WCF will run a single instance of that code in 2.4 seconds, and 64 in an average of 9 seconds, and never experience significant CPU utilization on either.

Are we using GRPC wrongly? Is there something wrong with the test? What can we do to make GRPC run a little faster/leaner?

Comment: GRPC is better than WCF in terms of performance. You can refer to the following link, which compares WCF with GRPC.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/grpc-for-wcf-developers/why-grpc

Comment: @Dingpeng totally makes sense, except that my testing doesn't at all show that. I don't know what I could be doing wrongly to get my results, though.

Comment: WCF itself cannot be compared to grpc. You should be comparing binding part of WCF to grpc.

Comment: @Alexander.Furer I don't understand what you mean.  I'm comparing performance when using GRPC to get a string vs when using WCF to get that same string. Why is that invalid?

Comment: WCF can be configured to use different bindings, each with its overhead... some minor, same major.